# How to replicate Memcache data among servers

Tags: java, memcached

A same question in SO can be found from here . But since I couldn't find any suitable answer, I am asking with additional info.

I have many memcache clients but all of them access one memcache server currently. I want to start new couple of memcache instances (to handle the caching load) and replicate data among them (to avoid fail overs and data high availability).

I took a look at 'repcached' and as I found, it supports only replication among 2 instance(one is master and one slave) since I want to have more memcache servers it doesn't make sense that repcached is not a solution for me.

Also as mentioned in the same question(in my first top line), it suggests to implement replication from client side. How ever it won't be a good fit as where all my memcache clients used are memory performance sensitive locations.(my application requirement.)

Therefore, any one let me any sugession or solution how I can make memcache servers/instances replicate (any central location where all caches replicate among servers)? (all data will be duplicated , and any methodology like, master(write only) and slave(read) where master is down, the slave becomes the master ).

Answer (score 5):

[CouchBase](http://www.couchbase.com) has memcached compatible API, and it has replication and persistence features in addition to standard memcached features.

Comment: Thank you v much. As far as I know, CouchBase is a NoSql database. How can I get the memcached services through CouchBase.

Comment: http://www.couchbase.com/memcached is the page that tells how to use it as a memcached replacement. CouchBase implements Memcached key-value store interface, so it doesn't matter how it is implemented internally. You can simply replace your memcached with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is still turning up in Google searches.

I was recently trying to solve this problem and looked at couchbase. The product is still alive but the link provided in another answer is dead. I found the documentation for couchbase bewildering and gave up on it. Couchbase does provide replication and persistence.

There are a set of patches known as [repcached](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-memcached-with-repcached-built-in-server-side-replication-on-debian-lenny) which add this capability to memcached but they don't appear to be actively maintained / I was unable to untangle the dependencies on a modern iteration of Linux.

I chose to use [mcrouter](https://github.com/facebook/mcrouter) for replication along with haproxy (to find a working memcache instance) and wrote my own script, [mcseed](https://github.com/symcbean/mcseed), for initial data population.